# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Index Interface

Tags: c++, parsing, undefined, symbols

I am creating an interface called Index that will allow me to Index using either a hash table or a AVL tree. I am getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "IndexHash::IndexHash(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "IndexHash::IndexHash()", referenced from:
      Parser::createIndex()      in Parser.o
```

These are coming from the lines:

```
Index* mainIn;
// creates a new index pointer
if (indexType_ == 1) {
    mainIn = new IndexAVL();
} else if (indexType_ == 2) {
    mainIn = new IndexHash();
}
```

This worked when it was just the AVL tree.

Index.H

```
#ifndef INDEX_H
#define INDEX_H
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "WordEntry.h"
#include "Document.h"

class Index {   
public:
virtual WordEntry* search(WordEntry*&)=0;
virtual void insert(WordEntry*&)=0;
virtual void insert(string)=0;
virtual void printOut(ofstream&)=0;
virtual void createDocument(string, string, string)=0;
virtual int getNumberDocs()=0;
virtual void trim(string&)=0;
private:

};

#endif
```

IndexHash.h

```
#ifndef INDEXHASH_H
#define INDEXHASH_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "WordEntry.h"
#include "IndexHash.h"
#include "Document.h"
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

class IndexHash : public Index{
public:
IndexHash();
IndexHash(string);
IndexHash(const IndexHash&);
~IndexHash();
virtual WordEntry* search(WordEntry*&);
virtual void insert(WordEntry*&);
virtual void insert(string);
virtual void printOut(ofstream&);
virtual int getNumberDocs();
virtual void trim(string&);
virtual void createDocument(string, string, string);
int searchDocs(string);
Document* binarySearch(vector<Document*>*, int, int, int);
void quickSort(vector<Document*>*, int, int); 
private:
tr1::unordered_map< WordEntry*, vector<Document*> >* hashtable_;
vector<Document*>* seenDocs;

};

#endif  /* INDEXHASH_H */
```

IndexHash.cpp

```
#include "IndexHash.h"
#include "Document.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

IndexHash::IndexHash() {
      hashtable_ = new tr1::unordered_map< WordEntry*, vector<Document*> >;
      seenDocs = new vector<Document*>;
}
```

... it defines everything, it is just hard for me to copy and paste it in here and I am assuming the problems is in includes.

Comment: I noticed this line #include "IndexHash.h" in your IndexHash.h file, should it be changed to #include "Index.h"??

Comment: What compiler toolchain are you using and what command is being used to link the program?  It looks like `IndexHash.o` (or the library that contains it) is not being included in the link step properly.

Comment: The error messages complains about two of your constructors. Have you added the `IndexHash.cpp` file when you build the application?